# Program stops at MPI_Send

Tags: c, parallel-processing, mpi

Program stops working, when I execute it with more than 1 processor.
It stops at first `MPI_Send`
What am I doing wrong?

```
#include "mpi.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define SIZE 200000
#define SIZE2 256
#define VYVOD 1

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int NX, NT;
    double TK, UM, DX, DY, DT;
    double starttime, endtime;
    int numnode, rank, delta=0, ierr, NXnode;
    double **U;
    double **U1;
    double *sosed1;
    double *sosed2;
    int i, j, k;
    MPI_Status stats;
    NX = 1*(SIZE2+1);
    TK = 20.00;
    UM = 10.0;
    DX = 0.1;
    DY = DX;
    DT = 0.1;
    NT = (TK/DT);

    MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&numnode);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&rank);

    if(rank == 0)
        printf("\nTotal nodes: %d\n", numnode);

    NX = NX - 2;
    NXnode = (NX-(NX%numnode))/numnode;
    if (rank < (NX%numnode))
    {
        delta = rank * NXnode + rank + 1;
        NXnode++;
    }
    else
    {
        delta = rank * NXnode + (NX%numnode) + 1;
    }

    if(rank == 0){
        printf("Order counting complete, NXnode = %d\n", NXnode);
    }



    U = (double**)malloc(NXnode*sizeof(double*));
    U1 = (double**)malloc(NXnode*sizeof(double*));
    sosed1 = (double*)malloc(SIZE*sizeof(double));
    sosed2 = (double*)malloc(SIZE*sizeof(double));

    for (i=0; i < NXnode; i++)
    {
        U[i] = (double*)malloc(SIZE*sizeof(double));
        U[i][0]=0;
        U[i][SIZE-1]=0;
        U1[i] = (double*)malloc(SIZE*sizeof(double));
        U1[i][0]=0;
        U1[i][SIZE-1]=0;
        if (U[i]==NULL || U1[i]==NULL)
        {
            printf("Error at memory allocation!");
            return 1;
        }
    }

    MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    if(rank == 0){
        starttime = MPI_Wtime();
        printf("Array allocation complete\n");
    }

    for (i = 0; i < NXnode; i++)
    {
        for (j = 1; j < SIZE-1; j++)
        {
            if ((delta)<=(NXnode/2))
            {
                U1[i][j]=2*(UM/NXnode)*(delta+i);
            }
            else
            {
                U1[i][j]=-2*(UM/NXnode) + 2*UM;
            }
        }
    }

    printf("Array init 1 complete, rank %d\n", rank);

    MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    if (rank > 0)
    {
        MPI_Send(&(U1[0][0]), SIZE, MPI_DOUBLE , rank-1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        MPI_Recv(&(sosed1[0]), SIZE, MPI_DOUBLE , rank-1, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &stats);
    }
    else
    {
        int initInd = 0;
        for (initInd = 0; initInd < SIZE; initInd++)
        {
            sosed1[initInd]=0;
        }
    }

    if (rank < (numnode-1))
    {
        MPI_Send(&(U1[NXnode-1][0]), SIZE, MPI_DOUBLE , rank+1, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        MPI_Recv(&(sosed2[0]), SIZE, MPI_DOUBLE , rank+1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &stats);
    }
    else
    {
        int initInd = 0;
        for (initInd = 0; initInd < SIZE; initInd++)
        {
            sosed2[initInd]=0;
        }
    }

    printf("Send complete, rank %d\n", rank);

    MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    printf("Array init complete, rank %d\n", rank);

    for (k = 1; k <= NT; k++)
    {
        int cycle = 0;
        for (cycle=1; cycle < SIZE-1; cycle++)
        {
            U[0][cycle] = U1[0][cycle] + DT/(DX*DX)*(U1[1][cycle]-2*U1[0][cycle]+sosed1[cycle])+DT/(DY*DY)*(U1[0][cycle+1]+U1[0][cycle-1]-(U1[0][cycle]*2));
        }
        for (i=1; i<NXnode-1; i++)
        {
            for(j=1; j<SIZE-1; j++)
            {
                U[i][j] = U1[i][j] + DT/(DX*DX)*(U1[i+1][j]-2*U1[i][j]+U[i-1][j])+DT/(DY*DY)*(U1[i][j+1]+U1[i][j-1]-(U1[i][j]*2));
            }
        }
        for (cycle=1; cycle < SIZE-1; cycle++)
        {
            U[NXnode-1][cycle]=U1[NXnode-1][cycle]+DT/(DX*DX)*(sosed2[cycle]-2*U1[NXnode-1][cycle]+U1[NXnode-2][cycle])+DT/(DY*DY)*(U1[NXnode-1][cycle+1]+U1[NXnode-1][cycle-1]-(U1[NXnode-1][cycle]*2));
        }

        /*U[0] = U1[0]+DT/(DX*DX)*(U1[0+1]-2*U1[0]+sosed1);
        for (j = 0; j<NXnode; j++)
        {
            U[j]=U1[j]+DT/(DX*DX)*(U1[j+1]-2*U1[j]+U1[j-1]);
        }
        U[NXnode-1]=U1[NXnode-1]+DT/(DX*DX)*(sosed2-2*U1[NXnode-1]+U1[(NXnode-1)-1]);*/

        if (rank > 0)
        {
            MPI_Send(&(U[0][0]), SIZE, MPI_DOUBLE , rank-1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        }
        if (rank < (numnode-1))
        {
            MPI_Send(&(U[NXnode-1][0]), SIZE, MPI_DOUBLE , rank+1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        }

        if (rank > 0)
        {
            MPI_Recv(&(sosed1[0]), SIZE, MPI_DOUBLE , rank-1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &stats);
        }
        if (rank < (numnode-1))
        {
            MPI_Recv(&(sosed2[0]), SIZE, MPI_DOUBLE , rank+1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &stats);
        }
        for (i = 0; i<NXnode; i++)
        {
            for (j=0; j<SIZE; j++)
            {
                U1[i][j]=U[i][j];
            }
        }
    }

    MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        printf("Array count complete, rank %d\n", rank);

    if (rank == 0)
    {
        endtime=MPI_Wtime();
        printf("\n## TIME: %f\n", endtime-starttime);
    }

     MPI_Finalize();
}
```

UPDATE#1
Tried it like that, so rank 0 would be the first, still doesn't work:

```
MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);

if (rank == 0 && numnode > 1)
{
    MPI_Recv(&(sosed2[0]), SIZE, MPI_DOUBLE , rank+1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &stats);
    MPI_Send(&(U1[NXnode-1][0]), SIZE, MPI_DOUBLE , rank+1, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    int initInd = 0;
    for (initInd = 0; initInd < SIZE; initInd++)
    {
        sosed1[initInd]=0;
    }
}
else if (rank == 0)
{
    int initInd = 0;
    for (initInd = 0; initInd < SIZE; initInd++)
    {
        sosed2[initInd]=0;
        sosed1[initInd]=0;
    }
}
else if (rank < (numnode-1))
{
    MPI_Send(&(U1[0][0]), SIZE, MPI_DOUBLE , rank-1, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Recv(&(sosed1[0]), SIZE, MPI_DOUBLE , rank-1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &stats);
    MPI_Recv(&(sosed2[0]), SIZE, MPI_DOUBLE , rank+1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &stats);
    MPI_Send(&(U1[NXnode-1][0]), SIZE, MPI_DOUBLE , rank+1, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
}
else if (rank == (numnode - 1))
{
    MPI_Send(&(U1[0][0]), SIZE, MPI_DOUBLE , rank-1, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Recv(&(sosed1[0]), SIZE, MPI_DOUBLE , rank-1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &stats);
    int initInd = 0;
    for (initInd = 0; initInd < SIZE; initInd++)
    {
        sosed2[initInd]=0;
    }
}
```

UPDATE#2
Solved, used same tag for all Send/Recv.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MPI_Send` is blocking the execution until the corresponding `MPI_Recv` is invoked (presumably in another process).

In your program, all processes except rank=0 are calling `MPI_Send` immediately after the first barrier, and no one is ready to `Recv` the message, so `MPI_Send` blocks infinitely. Essentially, every process is waiting for its message to be accepted by the process with the lower rank (rank 2 is waiting for rank 1, rank 1 is waiting for rank 0), and rank 0 is not accepting any messages at all (it goes to the next block of code and in turn calls `MPI_Send` too), so everything just hangs.

It looks like you are missing communication part for the process with rank=0 (it should do something like `MPI_Recv(from rank 1); ...; MPI_Send(to rank 1);`.

Another thing is that you use `MPI_Send` with tag `1`, but call `MPI_Recv` with tag `0`. This won't couple. You need to use the same tag, or to specify `MPI_TAG_ANY` in the receive operation.

Comment: Please, take a look at the UPDATE#1

Comment: Looks better. Now I noticed that you are using different tags for send and receive. For the operations to match each other, you need to use the same tag. I updated the answer.